"てかないません" What does it mean here? What kind of nuance does it provide?
「まぁ。あれくらいの癒やしがなければ　島民もやっていられなかったでしょうね」
「どこにいても潮風が纏わり付いて、　気持ち悪くてかないませんから」
The character is commenting on the quality of a hot spring. In the first line he says if it  wasn't so soothing, the islanders would not have made it.  Then he adds the sea breezes clings around everywhere and it feels disgusting.
So it adds "かないません" I can't quite make sense of it.  As far I know "かないません" means "no match for x" so what I'm  missing?

This is the grammar point “てかなわない”. Without the は, as in your example, the meaning is similar to “てならない・てたまらない”, albeit slightly more literary.
